# C# How can I do a string replace method on the collection?

Tags: c#, collections

I have the following method which return a collection so I can then build a dropdown menu from in MVC. The problem is, I want to replace a substring within the values in the collection but I am not sure how to do so in C# (I'm a classic vb guy).

```
public class RolesManagement
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> BuildRoles(string DesiredRole)
    {
        var UserRoles = Roles.GetAllRoles();

        IEnumerable<string> roles;
        roles = UserRoles.Where(x => x.Contains("Sub")).Except(rejectAdmin);
        return roles;
    }

}
```

The above has been simplified for brevity. Each role in the roles collection looks like this:
SubUser
SubAdmin
SubManager.

I simply want to return
User
Admin
Manager

What would be the best approach for this in C# please?

My guess is that I have to do a foreach and replace the substring on each loop and the re-populate the value before moving to the next item.

If you could provide a code sample that would be great as I seem to still me tripping over syntax issues.

Much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand you, what is `rejectAdmin`, what `roles` should contain and what are you trying to replace?

Comment: That query lists other options that I do not want returned in the roles collection. You do not need to concern yourself with that. Just know that this linq returns SubUser,SubAdmin,SubManager. But I want this displayed to be User, Admin, Manager. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that with LINQ.

```
roles = UserRoles
    .Where(x => x.Contains("Sub"))
    .Except(rejectAdmin)
    .Select(x => x.Replace("Sub", ""));
```

Edit: Note that this method simply replaces all occurrences of the string "Sub" in all of the strings in `roles`. It's a very broad stroke and you may need to use a different lambda function if you only want to do the replacements you mentioned. See Romoku's post for help with that.

Comment: Thank you for this. I chose this response as it was the closest approach to my original code. It's nice that this can be handled within the LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

I would say if the roles are not going to change very often then make a mapping `Dictionary`.

```
public class RolesManagement
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string,string> RoleMapping =
        new Dictionary<string,string>
        {
            {"SubUser", "User" },
            {"SubManager", "Manager" },
            {"SubAdmin", "Admin" }
        };

    public static IEnumerable<string> BuildRoles(string DesiredRole)
    {
        var UserRoles = Roles.GetAllRoles();

        IEnumerable<string> roles;
        roles = UserRoles.Where(x => x.Contains("Sub")).Except(rejectAdmin);
        return roles.Select(r => RoleMapping.ContainsKey(r) ? RoleMapping[r] : r);
    }
}
```

Or just store them inside the database as a `FriendlyName` column.

Answer (score 1):

this will return all items start with sub, with the sub removed

`IEnumerable<string> = UserRoles
    .Where(x => x.StartsWith("sub"))
    .Select(y =>  y.Remove(0,3));`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetCorrectedRoleNames(IEnumerable<string> roles)
{
    List<string> correctedRoles = new List<string>();
    foreach (string role in roles)
        correctedRoles.Add(Regex.Replace(role, "Sub", string.Empty));
    return correctedRoles.AsEnumerable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static IEnumerable<string> BuildRoles(string DesiredRole)
{
    var UserRoles = Roles.GetAllRoles();

    IEnumerable<string> roles;
    roles = UserRoles.Where(x => x.Contains("Sub")).Except(rejectAdmin).Select(x=>x.Replace("Sub","");
    return roles;
}
```

i supposed that x is `string` variable if not you have to do this replace on string collection

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem right, you need to remove the occurence of "Sub" in a string. You can do additional checks if you have other conditions , like "Sub" is at the beginning of the string, case-insensitivity, etc.

One of the ways is to find the index of the string to be removed and then remove.

```
var s = "SubUser";
var t = s.Remove(s.IndexOf("Sub"), "Sub".Length);
```

Alternatively, you can also replace the string to be removed with an empty string.

```
var t = s.Replace("Sub", "");
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
List<string> x = new List<string>();
x.Add("SubUser");
x.Add("SubAdmin");
x.Add("SubManager");

var m = x.Select( y => y.Replace("Sub", ""));
```